# WordPress Loop Through Particular Pages

Tags: loop

I have the following code setup as a page template and assigned to a page:

```
        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : 
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
            <?php
            echo $post->ID;
            $thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'Thumbnail', true);
            ?>
            <p><img src="<?php echo $thumb; ?>"</p>         

            <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

                <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                <?php the_excerpt();  ?>

                <?php the_content(); ?>
            </div><!-- #post-## -->

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

I curently have this page template on post=21. Now this all work fine but it only works for the page this template is assigned to.

I actually don't want this to be part of a template but I just want to use the code within my index.php file but I actually would like it to loop through these pages, i.e. 21,22,23 only, inorder to retrieve the info I have requested here.

Can someone please assist on how to pass the page id into this loop or how to make it loop just through pages 21,22 and 23.

This has got me stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: Please work on your questions. You got dozens of answers. If one fits: Mark it as solution. If not: comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

before your code, add:

```
<?php query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'page, 'post__in' => array(21,22,23), 'orderby' => 'ID', 'order' => 'ASC') ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Parameters

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this

```
$thepages = array (21,22,23);
foreach ($thepages as $thepage) {
  $page_data = get_page( $thepage );
  echo "<h3>$page_date->post_title</h3>";
  echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
  // spray out other page content
 }
```

See more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page)

Comment: thanks for that but just wondering, how can I access a post thumbnail that I have setup as a custom field of 'thumbnail' using your approach. Thanks.

Comment: should use `get_pages` and do it one query rather than 3 queries in a loop, more efficient.

Comment: I tried the get_pages approach and couldn't get it going - is there anything different I need to do apart from the function call?