# Loop through pages with specific template

Tags: loop, templates

I would like to know how I can loop through pages with a specific template name.
I have several pages where the admin can select a template name of `SALE`. I want to display all content with this template name via the loop.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Kindly refer : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46582/wordpress-loop-through-particular-pages

Comment: @HelpingHands thanks, but as far I can see its an example with page IDs. I want to display the pages via template! Could you still help me with this?

Comment: Does that link not helping you? shared by @Bainternet??

Comment: @HelpingHands sorry but what link to you mean? Cannot see a user named `Bainternet`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wordpress saves page templates that is assigned to a specific page in the db in the `wp_postmeta` table.

These are saved as follows:

```
'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
'meta_value' => 'NAME_ OF_TEMPLATE'
```

With this in mind, you can loop through pages which shares a specific page template, using `get_pages` (*You can also make use of `WP_Query`*)

Example:

```
$pages = get_pages(array(
    'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
    'meta_value' => 'page-special.php'
));
foreach($pages as $page){
    echo $page->ID.'<br />';
    echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $page->post_content );
}
```

Comment: thanks, this works well. Only one thing: if I would like to have every content of `$page` would I do `echo $page->the_content`? Because this gives me an error.

Comment: Check my update. You have to make use of the [`WP_Post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post) objects. You cannot use the normal template tags :-)

Comment: My pleasure, glad it worked. Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_template_part`, for example if your template is named *sale.php* you can use:

```
get_template_part( 'sale' );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_part

Comment: thanks but this does not really solve what I intend, or I dont understand it as I should.. basically what I want to do is do a new query and instead of selecting a specific post, I  select a specific template: `new WP_Query("template_name=sale");` something like this?

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense, WordPress info is stored in a database and not a template.